# Why this code throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java

Below code showing the NullPointerException after writing the file why it showing this .

```
OutputStream opStream  = null;
try {
   opStream = new FileOutputStream(wavFilePath);    
   opStream.write(wavData);
   opStream.flush();
   opStream.close();
} finally {
   if (opStream!=null)
        opStream.close();
        opStream = null;        
   }
```

Comment: Fastest way to an answer is to step through your code line-by-line with a debugger.  Have you tried doing that before posting on SO?

Comment: Stacktrace? I guess `wavFilePath` (or `wavData`) is probably `null`

Comment: Yes tried but some where its going wrong i am setting value for wavFilePath

Comment: I believe the fastest way is to inspect the StackTrace - then, if still necessary, use a debugger...

Comment: Your wavData is null, if <code>java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)</code>

Comment: your wavFilePath is null if <code>java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)</code>